# Is appname.exe.config required for user specific settings?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, settings

I'm building a simple winforms application which is using built-in settings for saving program options. All of the settings are per-user.

As I can see from the generated cs file the default settings are embedded in the source code but the application still reads the appname.exe.config file when launched. If I delete the file the application seems to be working fine but I want to make sure that it will not break anything.

So is the file required if I am only using per-user settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings designer embeds the default value in a [DefaultSettingValue] attribute.  The following section in the Remarks section of the attribute is relevant:

> Different settings providers may have
>   different requirements or limitations
>   on the use of the
>   DefaultSettingValueAttribute. For
>   example, the LocalFileSettingsProvider
>   does not require this attribute, and
>   will override any value provided by
>   this attribute if there are any
>   values—default or user-modified—
>   already present in the data store.

LocalFileSettingsProvider is the default provider.  So, it's there but it doesn't get used.

Comment: if the LocalFileSettingsProvider is ignoring the DefaultSettingValueAttribute then what values will the settings have when the application is run first time and there is not config file with default values?

Comment: Can't say I've ever tried this, it never made any sense to do so.  Why don't you just try it yourself?  I suspect something goes kaplooey.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using user settings instead of a configuration file. Refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750.aspx) article for more information, including how to read/write user settings.

Comment: I'm using user settings. The config file was automatically created by VS and when compiling it is renamed to myapp.exe.config I'm not using configuration file.

Comment: @Giorgi: That is a configuration file. It is created by default, even if you don't need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `Application Settings` and you want persistence of the settings then yes this is where the options are saved. If you delete the file it will simply recreate it if the user changes a setting and you are setting the setting.

Comment: The options are saved to appdata folder. The file only contains default values which are also present in Settings.Designer.cs